# How is lasso an M-Estimator?

Tags: estimation, lasso

The definition of an M-estimator is an estimator (from Casella and Berger) of the form 
$$\hat{\theta}=\min \sum_{i=1}^n \rho(X_i-\theta),$$

where $X_1,X_2, \cdots, X_n$ is the data for some function $\rho$.

The LASSO estimate is defined as
$$\hat{\theta}=\min ||AX-\theta||_2^2 + \lambda ||\theta||_1,$$
for some matrix A, and a vector parameter $\theta$.

Many papers refer to LASSO as an M-estimator, which does not appear to be true. Am I missing something here? The definition seems to imply there can not be any M-estimator for a vector parameter.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article on M-estimators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-estimator) explicitly allows $\theta$ to be a vector parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with LASSO being referred to as a *conventional* M-Estimator, as the conventional M-Estimator does not have a constraint, leading to familiar unconstrained optimization problems. I think LASSO is generally referred to as a *regularized* M-Estimator, i.e. an M-estimator with a regularity parameter. This would be $\lambda$ on the $\mathcal{L}_1$ norm or (LASSO) $\mathcal{L}_2$ norm (Ridge). See [here](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/3765-a-unified-framework-for-high-dimensional-analysis-of-m-estimators-with-decomposable-regularizers.pdf) for a nice description of the problem.

Comment: Thanks, but even $\min ||AX-\theta||_2^2$$ does not appear to be an M-estimator by the definition, right?

Comment: The definition you supply in the question doesn't appear to be correct. That would make quasilikelihood and GEE not a form of M estimation which isn't the case.

Comment: You are right. Many other papers like http://www4.stat.ncsu.edu/~boos/papers/mest6.pdf seem to define an M-estimator differently. They define an M-estimator as an estimator obtained by solving equations of the form $\sum_{i=1}^n \psi(X_i,\theta)=0$ as an M-estimator, in which case even least squares is an M-estimator. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this is more cohesive with my knowledge. The solution to an optimization problem (as in the case of the argmin definition) boils down to a linear root-finding problem (for "nice" problems) and well suited to Newton Raphson optimization. Optimizing over a general space can be very mean... however regularized M-estimators behave nicely because it is a type of dynamic optimization that can be solved with Lagrange multipliers.